Let $w$ be a bi-infinite word with alphabet $\{x_1,\ldots,x_d\}$. Let $c_w(n)$ be the number of distinct length $n$-sub-words of $w$
Let $w$ be a bi-infinite word with alphabet $\{x_1,\ldots,x_d\}$. Let $c_w(n)$ be the number of distinct length $n$-sub-words of $w$ and $\gamma_w(n)=c_w(1)+\cdots+c_w(n)$. Show that $\gamma_w(n)\sim nc_w(n)$. Also, is it true that $n\gamma_w(n)\sim \gamma_w(n)$?
For two functions $f,g:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$, we say $f\sim g$ if there is $A,B,C,D>0$ such that $f(n)\le Ag(Bn)$ and $g(n)\le Cf(Dn)$ for all $n$.
Now, we observe that $c_w$ is increasing function: Let $W(n)$ be the set of all length $n$-subwords of $w$. Let us denote $w[i,j]$ be the subword of $w$ starting at $i$th place and ending at $j$th place. Then, $W(n)=\{w[i,j]:\, i-j+1=n\}$. Define $\phi:W(n)\to W(n+1)$ by $\phi(w[i,j])=w[i,j+1]$. This $\phi$ is injective. Hence, $c_w(n)\le c_w(n+1)$. Therefore, $\gamma_w(n)\le nc_w(n)$.
But I am unable to show that $A\, nc_w(Bn)\le\gamma_w(n)$ for some $A,B>0$. Also, I am curious whether $n\gamma_w(n)\sim \gamma_w(n)$?
Can anybody help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Let me drop the index $w$ to simplify formulas. Since $c$ is increasing, one has
$$
nc(n) \leqslant c(n+1) + c(n+2) + \dotsm + c(2n) \leqslant \gamma(2n)
$$
and thus $\gamma(n) \sim nc(n)$.
However, $n\gamma(n) \not\sim \gamma(n)$. Take the one letter alphabet $\{a\}$ and the bi-infinite word $\dotsm aaaaa \dotsm$. Then $c(n) = 1$ and $\gamma(n) = n$, but $n^2 \not\sim n$.
